# Convert 360 Spherical to Equirectangular projection using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I have video ouput from a LGE 360 camera in 360 spherical format. I want to upload to youtube.
Before I do so however this must be converted into equirectangular projection.

Is there a way to do this via FFMPEG?

Comment: In theory, yes. Using the [remap](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-remap) filter. But you need to have or construct the [maps](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter) for your camera input.